# Shortest distance between a particular node and a point

Tags: c++

is there any faster way to find the shortest distance between a particular node (x,y) and a point (out of many points)? Or using brute force is the only way to do it? I'm dealing with like thousands of points in this case. I'm using a software called CodeBlocks for this task. Currently using this.

```
inline double dist(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    return sqrt( (p1.x - p2.x)*(p1.x - p2.x) +
                 (p1.y - p2.y)*(p1.y - p2.y) );
}

double bruteForce(Point P[], int n, Point &p1)
{
    double min = DBL_MAX;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        if (dist(p1, P[i]) < min) {
                min = dist(p1, P[j]);
        }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure he means faster than exhaustive comparison. It is implied from his following sentence.

Comment: i'm dealing with 2D points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual fast methods use things like quad-trees or oct-trees (for 2D and 3D points respectively) or R-trees.

Answer (score 0):

You could set it up so each point has it's own distance variable (like objects of a class). Then check that particular variable to see which one is closest.

Answer (score 0):

Space Partitioning solves this in `O(log N)` where `N` is the size of your points space.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#Methods